# Trying to change text size on randomly returned text

Tags: html, fonts, size

I'm making a web page that just returns a random line of text from a pool. Currently it just spits it out in one size and font and I'm trying to figure out how I could get it to come out at least at a bigger size for now. This is the code I'm using right now:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Random Text</title>


  <div id="quote404"></div>

  <script>
    
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        {text: "text1"},
        {text: "text2"},
        {text: "text3"},
        {text: "text4"},
      //{text: "text5"},
      //{text: "text6"},
      //{text: "text7"},
   
        
      ];
      var quote404 = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
       document.getElementById("quote404").innerHTML =
        '<p align="center">' + quote404.text + '</p>'
    
       ;
   
    })();
    
  </script>
  
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I've looked around for a bit and THINK I should be using

```
.style.fontsize = "__px"
```

somewhere but I've tried putting that code in different places in the current code and most of the time it just ends up causing no text to come out.

I've also tried using

```
'<font size="__">' '</font>'
```

within the paragraph tag and that didn't work either.

Comment: You can try `<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px">`

Comment: BTW **The align attribute of <p> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead**. So going the css way. [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_p_align.asp)

Comment: Thank you! This worked just fine and gave me a clue as to where to put more modifications should I try to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `style` property to add css to your paragraph.
So it would look something like this:

```
var quote404 = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
document.getElementById("quote404").innerHTML = '<p align="center" style="font-size: "' +(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min) +'";">' + quote404.text + '</p>';
```

This would change the size of the text between the min number you specify and the max number you specify.

If you just want to make the text bigger use:

```
var quote404 = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
document.getElementById("quote404").innerHTML = '<p align="center" style="font-size: 30px;">' + quote404.text + '</p>';
```

This will change your font size to `30px`. You can play around with that to find the best size.

Comment: Thanks! I have to say I am interested in the method of returning a random font size each time but I have some more learning to do before I figure out how exactly to implement the way you provided here. I'll keep it in mind though.